# After Login, My index.php redirects to Login.php

Tags: php

i have used this code for years and never experienced this, using a new hosting service prior to the ones i have always used and am getting this issue.

```
        session_start();

$rec_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$cPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['isadmin'])){
    header('location: login.php?l=i');
}

include('includes/constants.php');
include('includes/functions.php');

$admin_login = $_SESSION['login'];
$admin_psw = GetAdminInfo($admin_login,'1');


if(isset($_REQUEST['cmd'])){
    if($_REQUEST['cmd']=="logout"){
        session_destroy();
        header('location: login.php');
    }
        }
```

this is the section of the code with the issues, once i login i get redirected to the login.php if i delete this

```
`if(!isset($_SESSION['isadmin'])){
header('location: login.php?l=i');
}`
```

i can login successfully but if i click on another page i will have to login again, so im guessing its a Session problem.

here is the action php for the login.php

```
        <?php

include('../includes/constants.php');
include('../includes/functions.php');

if(isset($_POST['xin'])){

    $ikey = addslashes($_POST['textKey']);
    $nkey = addslashes($_POST['textname']);
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die('Cannot connect to db');
    mysqli_select_db($mysqli, $db_db) or die('Cannot select db');
    
    $result=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE login = '".$ikey."' && adminname = '".$nkey."'");
    $cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($cnt > 0){
        while($rw=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['isadmin']=true;
            $_SESSION['login'] = $ikey;
            $_SESSION['adminname'] = $nkey;
            header('location: ../index.php?cm='.$_SESSION['isadmin']);
        }
    }else{
        header('location: ../login.php?err=1'.mysqli_error($mysqli));
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you done a var_dump of $_SESSION to check if the variable is being set?

Comment: check $_SESSION['isadmin'] have value in this key

Comment: All we know here is that your `if`-statement doesn't evaluate as true. But since we don't know how/where are you setting that session value and that you haven't added any form of debugging info, I'm not sure what we can do here? Do you have `session_start()` before any output on all pages (or requests) you're reading the session from? Could it be that your old server had session autostart?

Comment: you should exit after setting location headers, if you don't then the code after gets run.

Comment: You have to add session_start(); line  to all your pages where you are using session so Please check that session start on that page or not.

Comment: @CloudTheWolf did a Var_dump of $_session, came out null. so i guess the variable is not being set

Comment: @ByronMoola try moving `session_start();` to the start of the file, directly below `<?php`

Answer (score 0):

use javascript instead of header. No long story

```
echo "<script>parent.self.location='index.php';</script>";
```

Comment: same issue the index.php redirects to the login.php

Comment: you need to exit immediately after using the script like so
echo "<script>parent.self.location='index.php';</script>";
exit();

Comment: @ByronMoola were you able to fix this?

Comment: i wasn't, same looping issue ... this same code works well on other hosting service i have tried and still using , not just on hosting24.com